# XNA 4.0 - Load texture without background

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

how to draw sprite without background. For example display this:

[image]

without green background.

I'm using XNA 4.0.

I don't want to edit all textures :/

Thanks ;)

SOLUTION !
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uw0PK.jpg 
`Image Properties -> Content Processor -> Color Key Color` - it's a colow which we will remove.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What have you tried so far?  Have you done any research?  Let us know more.  Also consider the [Stack Overflow Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for how to ask really neat questions

Answer (score 0):

You need to save it as a .PNG From .net Paint and remove the alpha, so that when you import it it is blank.

you can find .Net paint [here](http://www.getpaint.net/)